# How can I write a value to a file without it being overwritten? using Rscript

Tags: r, file

I have a script that I pass a different input and get a different output every time, so I want to write all the outputs to a file, but every time I run the script with a new value, the value in the file gets overwritten. So how can I write all the outputs to a file without overwriting them?
This is the function I used to write to the file.

```
write(sum1, file = "C:/Users/ayera/Desktop/values.txt",
      append = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

Answer (score 3):

The **`append=`** option **means** ***'add to the end'*** ***if set to `TRUE`***, so it doesn't overwrite the previous values:

```
write(sum1, file = "C:/Users/ayera/Desktop/values.txt", append = TRUE, sep = ",")
```